# Parameter functioning in SSMS but not SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, ssms

Assume I have the following query (simplified version of what im really using)...

```
DECLARE @p_ServerName nvarchar(10)
SELECT  SystemName FROM Table_x
WHERE   SystemName = @p_ServerName OR @p_ServerName = 'all'
```

When I set the parameter to a specific name ex: DB1 the rows are displayed in SSRS 
but when I input 'all' as the parameter, nothing is displayed. Yet when I do the same in SSMS it works just fine.

Does anyone know what can be the problem here?
Thanks.

EDIT

Here is the first query I tried (ignore the declares, it was just used for ssms testing in which it worked just fine):

```
DECLARE    @p_ServerName nvarchar(10) = 'all'
DECLARE    @p_Env        nvarchar(10) = 'all'
DECLARE    @p_EnvCat     nvarchar(10) = 'all'

SELECT DISTINCT    
           c1.BlockSize, c1.BootVolume, c1.Compressed, c1.SystemName, c1.Label, c1.Caption, c1.PageFilePresent,
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', c1.Capacity) AS Capacity,
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', c1.FreeSpace) AS [Free Space], 
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', c1.Capacity - c1.FreeSpace) AS [Used Space],
           100 * c1.FreeSpace / c1.Capacity AS [Free Space %],
           [CLE_ENV_SHORT], [CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT]

FROM       CCS_Win32_Volume c1

JOIN       [dbo].[CCS_V_SERVER_INSTANCE_DETAILS] c2 on c1.SystemName = c2.CSL_SERVER_NAME

WHERE     (c1.SystemName = @p_ServerName OR c1.SystemName = c1.SystemName)
     AND   (c2.[CLE_ENV_SHORT] = @p_Env OR @p_Env = 'all')
     AND   (c2.[CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT] = @p_EnvCat OR @p_EnvCat = 'all')

ORDER BY   c2.[CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT], c2.[CLE_ENV_SHORT]
```

Here is the other query i tried (again ignore the declares):

```
    DECLARE    @p_ServerName nvarchar(10) = 'all'
    DECLARE    @p_Env        nvarchar(10) = 'all'
    DECLARE    @p_EnvCat     nvarchar(10) = 'all'

    SELECT DISTINCT   
           c1.SystemName, c1.BlockSize, c1.BootVolume, c1.Compressed, c1.Label, c1.Caption, c1.PageFilePresent,
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', c1.Capacity) AS Capacity,
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', c1.FreeSpace) AS [Free Space], 
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', c1.Capacity - c1.FreeSpace) AS [Used Space],
           100 * c1.FreeSpace / c1.Capacity AS [Free Space %],
           [CLE_ENV_SHORT], [CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT]
    FROM       CCS_Win32_Volume c1
    JOIN       [dbo].[CCS_V_SERVER_INSTANCE_DETAILS] c2 on c1.SystemName = c2.CSL_SERVER_NAME
    WHERE      c1.SystemName = @p_ServerName
         AND   (c2.[CLE_ENV_SHORT] = @p_Env OR @p_Env = 'all')
         AND   (c2.[CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT] = @p_EnvCat OR @p_EnvCat = 'all')

    UNION

    SELECT DISTINCT    
           c1.SystemName, c1.BlockSize, c1.BootVolume, c1.Compressed, c1.Label, c1.Caption, c1.PageFilePresent,
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', c1.Capacity) AS Capacity,
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', c1.FreeSpace) AS [Free Space], 
           [dbo].[CCS_DIGITAL_STORAGE_CONVERTER]('B', 'GB', c1.Capacity - c1.FreeSpace) AS [Used Space],
           100 * c1.FreeSpace / c1.Capacity AS [Free Space %],
           [CLE_ENV_SHORT], [CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT]
    FROM       CCS_Win32_Volume c1
    JOIN       [dbo].[CCS_V_SERVER_INSTANCE_DETAILS] c2 on c1.SystemName = c2.CSL_SERVER_NAME
    WHERE      @p_ServerName = 'all'
         AND   (c2.[CLE_ENV_SHORT] = @p_Env OR @p_Env = 'all')
         AND   (c2.[CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT] = @p_EnvCat OR @p_EnvCat = 'all')

   ORDER BY   c2.[CLE_ENV_CAT_SHORT], c2.[CLE_ENV_SHORT], c1.SystemName
```

Since multiple variations of queries work fine in SSMS I am assuming the issue is how SSRS handles 'all'. Because when I enter any server name it works fine. Only 'all' has a problem. So I guess my question is, how do you set up parameters to do this?

Comment: So should I be using a CASE instead?

Comment: Ignore previous comment - that was incorrect.  Are you defining `@p_ServerName` somewhere?  I'm only seeing a declaration for `@p_Name`

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that "all" is the value that's actually being passed to the parameter?  Check your parameter mappings within your dataset and double check that @ p_ServerName is coming from Parameters!<yourParam>.Value  @Siyual - if the query is embedded into an SSRS dataset, parameters being populated from the RDL don't need to be explicitly declared.

Comment: @kyzen Gotcha, that makes sense.  In that case, if you are indeed passing in 'all' to the param, then the issue would not be in the provided code.  If that is the case, it would be helpful to see the actual code you're using.

Comment: How this value `'all'` is passed to the report? do you have a drop down or Users enter this value in a text box on reports manager? This simplified version of your actual query look fine to me. Post your actual query.

Comment: @Siyual sorry that was a typo, I edited the parameter declaration

Comment: will post my queries right now. (I have tried a couple)

Comment: How will that work? Parameter Flag input is 1 or 0, so I only get two queries but I want to be able to pick either all Servers or just one specific one that I type in  @AHiggins

Comment: Can you confirm that your parameters are receiving their values correctly by replacing everything in your query pane with a SELECT statement returning just your variable values?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean? (SQL is new to me...)

Comment: @M.Ali users would input it

Comment: What I'm wondering is if you can return "SELECT p_ServerName, p_Env, p_EnvCat" as your SSRS dataset and see if it is correctly interpreting your parameters.  (SO doesn't like my using the 'at' symbol, so add that before your parameter names.)

Comment: @AHiggins is on the right track here.  Also consider throwing a textbox on the report and printing the parameter values on it, so you can compare the value in the report to the value being returned by your query.

Comment: K so I just tried making a new dataset with what you mentioned. opened up dataset properties and in the parameter name is right, the value isnt but that makes sense since no where else is it being specified. It added Expr1 Expr3 Expr3 as fields with same as field source...

Is this what you wanted me to try out?

Comment: That sounds right, yes - do the values print out on the report as expected?

Comment: K so I created a text box to display what value for parameter is inputted... and when i input all, that is displayed. Now I am wondering, how does SSRS know that when I type ALL i really mean display all recored? I assumed by saying in my WHERE clause that if 'all' is entered then equal the parameter to itself to display everything... Again, That works in SSMS but not SSRS

Comment: This has been an ongoing problem for a couple days :(

Comment: Since multiple variations of queries work fine in SSMS I am assuming the issue is how SSRS handles 'all'. Because when I enter any server name it works fine. Only 'all' has a problem. So I guess my question is, how do you set up parameters to do this?

Comment: Since your SP sets default values for your params, have you tried passing (nothing/null) instead of "all" and making  your report param nullable/optional?

Comment: yes I have, no rows message is what i get... And it isn't a SP its just a query that I entered in the Dataset... Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It isn't very clear from your question which parameter you're having trouble implementing the "ALL" filtering on. But from looking at your two queries it looks like it is the `@p_ServerName` parameter. In your first query the other two seem to have had the 'ALL' filtering done properly.

So the problem must be here:

```
(c1.SystemName = @p_ServerName OR c1.SystemName = c1.SystemName)
```

First, what are you trying to achieve with the second part? `c1.SystemName=c1.SystemName` will always be true (unless c1.SystemName is `NULL` and if that is your goal then use `c1.SystemName IS NOT NULL`

I think this should look more like:

```
(c1.SystemName=@p_ServerName OR @p_ServerName='all')
```

Which is how you've implemented the other two parameters, so perhaps I'm missing something.

Also, I'm not sure what you mean when you say that the UNIONed query solution must be how SSRS is doing things. SSRS doesn't rewrite your queries based on the parameters, it just sticks that values in those variables for you to use in your query. If your parameter `@p_ServerName` is a string then it is just a VARCHAR variable with the characters "all" in it.

Comment: its actually all of them. For all of them the specific value i input works, but for all of them, the 'all' aspect does not

Comment: It must be something with how your parameters are configured then. Are they query driven? Are they strings? You need to do some testing to determine exactly what value is being stored when you select 'all' in the report. Because `DECLARE @p_ServerName VARCHAR(3) = 'all'` should be the same as assigning the same value to a string parameter in SSRS named `@p_ServerName`

Comment: Alternatively, you could make the @p_ServerName a multi-select parameter and just "Select All", but that may not fit your needs.

Comment: I added a text box to the report listing the values of parameters in preview... They all appear as what i input so yeah it must be how my parameters are set.

Comment: How do you get the select all? Whenever i add multi value its no different than before other than a blank drop down pane

Comment: That is pretty strange, I'm not really sure what is going on there. Displaying the parameter values in the report would be how I would check they are getting set properly. When you run the query in SSRS it will ask you to supply the parameter values and then show you the results. Does that work?

Comment: With a multi-select parameter that has choices defined (either driven via a query or hard coded in the parameter settings) I get a "Select all" option above all of the other choices in the drop-down list. If your drop-down is empty then you must not be supplying any values to select from.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Ill look into it some more